# How to write a function which will run a command a certain condition in output?

Tags: python, curl

I have a curl command which is having some issues sending data to proxy, so sometimes it sends the data perfectly other times it fails. The command looks like

```
curl --tlsv1 --cipher ALL --connect-timeout 90 -T nint.txt  ftps://ftp.box.com/Backup/nants.txt --user "admin:pass" -x socks4://10.21.0.10:1080 -v
```

Now i need to write a python code which executes this command until the output contains `Connection #0 to host ftp.box.com left intact`

something like

```
def send_to_box(zip_name):
    curl --tlsv1 --cipher ALL --connect-timeout 90 -T nint.txt  ftps://ftp.box.com/Backup/nants.txt --user "admin:pass" -x socks4://10.21.0.10:1080  2>&1 | grep -q "Connection #0 to host ftp.box.com left intact" "
    while "Connection #0 to host ftp.box.com left intact" in os.system(curl_cmd_grep):
           print successful send the data
```

Not sure what is the best way to achive this

Comment: Have a look at the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

Comment: yes i saw, but how to grep and run it with this condtion?

Comment: It looks like your are try to monitor a remote FTP directory. See this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12118011/1513933

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE I am trying to upload the content to remote FTPS server and the instance from which i am trying to upload sits behind a proxy

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Can you help

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE can you help

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ftputil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ftputil/3.3.1) which has a TLS support. See an example here: [Does ftputil support SSL/TLS?](http://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/trac/wiki/Documentation#does-ftputil-support-ssl-tls)

To use a proxy, consult this SO question: [Proxies in Python FTP application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1293518/1513933)

You can also search in the Python documentation: [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#module-ftplib) module.

Comment: i understand , but thats unclear to setup with , i am more of interested in doing the thing the dirty way