# Setting up proxy with FTP with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, ftp

We are trying to develop a Python module that will hit an FTP server and download files to my local machine. When we try to run the FTP portion of the module it is timing out.

We have a proxy server (let's call it "officeproxy.com:8080") to handle this and when using an FTP client like FileZilla or Windows Explorer to access FTP sites we are successful.

Let's call the ftp site "ftp.cal.com".  User name is "papa".  Password is "tango123".

So far we have:

```
Proxy = officeproxy.com:8080
FTP = ftp.cal.com
User = papa
PW = tango123
```

The above are not real entities so if you want to swap them out for real ones, be my guest.

I need a module to first load the proxy service then run the FTP portion.

I am running Python 2.7.

I have searched around and have this code so far.  The OP said it is just a short module to test connection to FTP and read one file.

(Note: I have intentionally put `#` in a lot of places to show when I don't know to fill in, or other reasons):

```
import urllib2
# I have filled in the proxy info
proxy_host = 'officeproxy.com:8080'

# I don't think this needs any modification, right?  
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'ftp': proxy_host})

# ditto here 
proxy_auth_handler = urllib2.ProxyBasicAuthHandler() 

# now here is where I am unsure what to put; 
# also, I really need FTP user and FTP password, and NOT Proxy... 
# so what do I need to change here?
proxy_auth_handler.add_password(None, proxy_host, proxy_user, proxy_passwd) 
opener_thru_proxy = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler, proxy_auth_handler)

# I filled in this part
conn = opener_thru_proxy.open('ftp://ftp.cal.com/hello.txt') 

# I don't believe I need to change this, right?
print conn.read()
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding this as it's one of the top results and struggled to find a solution.

If your proxy is a **HTTP proxy** and you need to **authenticate** it then this is how:

```
import socks
import socket

socks.set_default_proxy(socks.HTTP, 
        proxy_host, 
        proxy_port, 
        username=proxy_username, 
        password=proxy_password
)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
ftp = FTP(ftp_host)
ftp.set_debuglevel(1) 
ftp.login(
        user=ftp_user,
        passwd=ftp_password
)
```

Otherwise for a **FTP Proxy** Martin's answer works. You can see the behaviour in FileZilla for FTP proxies too and that'll help to code for your requirements

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: u saved my ass there. Also, I had ''550 SSL/TLS required on the control channel' error, and had to switch to FTP_TLS method and finally worked !

Answer (score 0):

Note, I found some [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293518/proxies-in-python-ftp-application) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768214/python-download-a-file-over-an-ftp-server) on SO, but as the OP requested a detailed, beginner-level answer, I decided to post this.

To clarify, here is my understanding of what you want to accomplish:

- You have an FTP server behind a proxy.
- The FTP server requires user/password credentials, but the proxy itself does not.

One option is to use the `ftplib` package. One of the great advantages of a popular language such as Python is the wide selection of packages the that provide good implementations of specific functionality. In this case, an ftp client:

```
import ftplib  # 1

ftp = ftplib.FTP("officeproxy.com:8080")  # 2
ftp.set_debuglevel(1)  # 3
ftp.login("papa", "tango123")  # 4

filename = "hello.txt"
f = open(filename, 'wb')  # 5 
ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + filename , f.write)  # 6

f.close()   # cleanup file handle
ftp.quit()  # cleanup ftp client
```

Here is what the code is doing:

1. Import the `ftplib` package.
2. Connect to the FTP server through the proxy. The way I have written it assume that the proxy is setup to forward the FTP protocol on the port specified (8080 in your example). *If this is not the case, this will not work.*
3. Enable debug logging. From [the ftplib documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.set_debuglevel):

> `FTP.set_debuglevel(level)`:  `0`, produces no debugging output... `1` produces a moderate amount of debugging output... `2` or higher produces the maximum amount of debugging output

4. Login to the FTP server using user="papa", passwd="tango123". Again, this is from the [ftplib documentation for login()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.login)
5. [Open a local file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) for writing the contents of file you are about to retrieve from the FTP server. The first argument is the filename for the file you want to save to (it can be anything, I decided to use the same filename as the filename on the FTP server). The second argument is the *mode* you want to open the file as, which is a string of flags: w = 'write mode', b = 'binary mode', because we are going to retrieve the file as binary and write it as binary.
6. I recommend you read the [ftplib documentation for retrbinary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrbinary). This is a bit tricky to understand at first. The first argument, `"RETR" +  filename` is the command to send to the FTP server, in this case `RETR hello.txt`. The second argument, `f.write` is the *callback* function you want the `ftp.retrbinary` function to call whenever it has a block of data from the server. In its implementation, whenever `retrbinary` has data, it will call `f.write(data)` where `data` is the latest block of data it has. To understand more how callbacks work in Python, see [Introduction to Asynchronous APIs in Python](https://www.import.io/post/introduction-to-asynchronous-apis-in-python/)

I hope this works for you, and I hope the answer is detailed enough that you understand how it works. If it does not work, please post the stack trace output for the error you get.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I will try to implement this today and will get back to you with the results!

Comment: I think we may have a slight miscommunication.  When I started to insert the code into the module, I realized that we are missing the FTP address (section #2).   So I wanted to reconvey the intended sequence of events.

Comment: Sorry, got cut off due to time limit.  Anyway, the miscommunication is my fault.  The FTP server is not ours, it belongs to our vendor and we have no control over it.  Our corporate IT department has done something to limit outgoing FTP requests from behind our firewall and that is why I need a way to circumvent the limitation using our proxy server instead.  I've used the proxy server effectively with an FTP client (FileZilla) so I know once I can get the Proxy initialized it can pass through.

Comment: Therefore, here is the sequence I believe needs to be followed: 1) Create proxy event handler (using officeproxy.com) no authentication is required yet at this point.  2) Create FTP handler to info which consists of  a) FTP address [ftp.cal.com], b) User [papa] and c) PW [tango123] to log in to FTP server.  IOW, the authentication takes place AFTER the proxy is initialized.  I hope this clarifies it some.

Comment: Oh I see now. Let me work on that a bit and update my answer.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks.

Comment: Hi @kevdoran - any luck on your revised answer?   Cheers!

Comment: @pelampe been busy the past few days, but about to have some downtime I can use to setup a test environment to mimic this and update the client code. Cheers!

Comment: @kevdoran can you pls do an example of your point 2 thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little bit out-dated, but I didn't find any recent solution myself so I figured I would provide the solution I found. In my case the office proxy requires credentials so those are included in the solution. I would presume that you can just remove the proxy_user and proxy_passwd if your proxy does not require credentials. The code I got working in Python 3.6 is:

```
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP("officeproxy.com")
ftp.set_debuglevel(1)
ftp.login(user='ftp_user@ftp_host proxy_user', passwd='ftp_passwd', acct='proxy_passwd')

# Do whatever you need on the FTP server here

ftp.quit()
```

I hope this helps.